# Data Loader - Connect Activity/Tasks to Quotes?

Tags: data-loader, activities, quote

I'm Data Loading from Org to Org.

Accounts, Contacts, Opportunities, Leads, Activities, Products, Price Books, and Quotes are all complete.

I just finished Quotes.

Activities/Tasks are showing on the Account.

**How do I connect Activity/Tasks to Quotes?**

Thanks

Comment: What is in your data? Do your Tasks' `WhatId` fields contain Quote Ids? How are you mapping that field when you do the import?

Comment: My Tasks `WhatId` contained Account Id's.

Comment: So I already inserted Tasks and assigned the `WhatId` to the Account so that the Task lives under the Account. Now that I've inserted Quotes, I'm wondering if I can link the Task to their quotes too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you are using a custom field, the Task/Event's "WhatId" field is polymorphic and can contain ids for Accounts, Opportunities.  Here's the quote from the documentation:

> The WhatId represents nonhuman objects such as accounts, opportunities, campaigns, cases, or custom objects. WhatIds are polymorphic. Polymorphic means a WhatId is equivalent to the ID of a related object. The label is Related To ID.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_task.htm

**So a Task whose WhatId begins with '0Q0' is a Quote task**.

Lastly, you can't use the "showing on Account" in the screen view as a good indicator.  I forget whether it's Lightning or Classic, but one of them "rolls up" certain tasks to display on the Account even if the Task is on certain child records.

Answer (score 0):

look at your schema.  If tasks are not a child of Quotes then they can't be done unless you map it.  I would imagine it would be easier to have them on the opportunity instead of the quote just so you don't have to search each quote for notes but I don't know your specific use case.

Schema Builder - https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=schema_builder.htm&type=5